# Updating firebaseAsArray item and save

Tags: angularjs, firebase

Hi am using firebase and angularfire as a backeng for an account web app,
am having problem design logic to handle this feature 
 Get object in ng repeat table 
 $scope the object into a form - and allow editing 
 save the updated $scope to the object( // maybe object key or $id

```
    $scope.records = $firebaseArray(data_records);
    // updating value
$scope.updateValue = {};
$scope.key = null;
$scope.showDoUpdate = false;

$scope.openUpdate = function(record, key) {
    $scope.showDoUpdate =  true;
    $scope.updateValue.customerCode = record.customerCode;
    $scope.updateValue.credit = record.credit;
    $scope.updateValue.debit = record.debit;
    $scope.updateValue.property_no = record.property_no;
    $scope.updateValue.arrears = record.arrears;
    $scope.updateValue.closingBlance = record.closingBlance;

    $scope.key = key;
};

$scope.closeUpdate = function() {
    $scope.records[key] = $scope.updateValue;
    $scope.records.$save();
    $scope.updateValue = {};
    $scope.key = null;
    $scope.showDoUpdate = false;
};
```

and in my html

```
 <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="(key,record) in records">
            <td>{{records.customerCode}}</td>
            <td>{{records.property_no}}</td>
       <td>
           <button class="btn" ng-    click="openUpdate(key,record)">edit</button>
        </td>


 <!--form ...........
         <button ng-click="closeUpdate()" class="btn ">Save</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

$index will help you.  Try something like...

```
ng-repeat="rec in records"
```

Then in your ng-click:

```
ng-click="openUpdate(records[$index].record, records[$index].key)"
```

Which will call...

```
$scope.openUpdate = function(record, key) {
    $scope.key = key;
    //other work
};
```